# Will it help my job application if I include some sample work?

Tags: applications, united-kingdom

I am applying for a job by completing a form online. One of the sections is for additional documentation. I am considering attaching some sample work, but I am unsure whether it will be read.

My question is, **is the sample work likely to benefit my application?**

---

**Info regarding the job/sample work**

If this is helpful, the job is in market research. I propose building a SWOT analysis of the hiring organisation using publicly accessible data in my own time (so there are no complaints from my current employer etc.)

Comment: Well, it can't hurt...

Comment: @JohnHC Of course it can. If the material isn't amazing or if OP is in sector where portfolios aren't really a thing, including something just to fill in a box could be very detrimental. Even if that's not the case, it takes a lot of effort to create quality sample work. Effort that would be entirely wasted in most fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the sample work likely to benefit my application?

Being able to demonstrate your work **can be a nice advantage over** other applicants. Having the courage to show your code also says a lot about you, if you are indeed in the software development industry.  (*I would suggest considering a GIT repo for this purpose if my assumption is correct.*)

Be sure the work is **yours**, and does not include any sensitive **data or code** from other past employers.  This way you're covered legally, but are still able to demonstrate your capability.

Also note that doing this is not a silver bullet as employers are also not stupid.  They realize that applications exists that can be modified to look like your custom application.

Best of luck on your job search.

Comment: " would suggest considering a GIT repo for this purpose if my assumption is correct." A github can be a real bonus here, plus you can do HTML/CSS pages for free if you want to show some webdesign skillz.

Comment: "If this is helpful, the job is in market research"... I question whether the OP knows what a GIT repo is.

Comment: This answer is certainly valuable for a developer, but for market research?

Comment: @LaurentS. I think the answer applies just fine, minus the git stuff.  If the marketing material ( Power point for example ) was created by the OP and is of good quality why not show it off?

Comment: @DanPichelman: course I know what a GIT repo is. It's one of those internet thingies that turns up on the telly box, right?